Jupyter "save and export" and "nbconvert" error
Everything worked fine in Jupyter 4.0.11.
When upgrading to 4.2.5 I don't see anything in the File menu when I want to "Save and Export Notebook As", and I also get an error for the "import nbconvert" cell.
Is there a way to fix this (reset, update, etc)?
I tried going back to 4.0.11, but still have the same issue.
I tried uninstalling nbconvert, but not sure if this was done correctly.
Please note that I'm new to programming and Jupyter, so detailed answers will be appreciated.

I think each time you write 'Jupyter' here, you mean 'JupyterLab'? Please correct your title and post text, if so. Do not uninstall nbconvert. It is part of how Jupyter tech that handles running .ipynb files works and will cause you issues. As a learner you should be cautious updating to the cutting-edge versions. Often it is more important to have working tech then to take the chance you'll mess up your system. If you haven't looked into it, you may wish to look into installing and using the Anaconda Distribution as it will keep things more isolated automatically and comes with versions...

 known to work well together. One drawback is that you have to learn how to work with it the way it expects and that can be daunting. Anaconda Cloud also gives you some abilities as a learner to use true Jupyter in your browser without touching your system.

Also, it would be nice if you detail the error you see when you run import nbconvert. You seem to skip over and want to reset and update. (For that you generally need to clean and purge if a basic rolling back failed as you say.) Alternatively, or why you sort this, since you say ' I'm new to programming and Jupyter', you may be interested in working with other sources of ways to edit and run active .ipynb in your browser, see  here. Try Jupyter is currently best for Jupyterlite.
